# Why does Mule-ESB in an Ubuntu environment not use the default Java key store?

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssl, mule

This question may be Java related or it may be Mule related. I just don't know, which is why I'm asking it under both tags.

My problem is this: I develop Mule applications using Mule Studio (although I do most of my configuring through XML, it's just more powerful). Until recently, we used a Windows environment to host applications. So whatever worked on my development machine worked on the server.

However, we recently switched from a Windows to an Ubuntu server environment. When I started migrating my Mule applications I noticed that it simply refused to connect to any endpoint over the HTTPS protocol. A little research showed that the following exception occured:

```
subject/issuer name chaining check failed (java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException)
```

So a certificate problem. It shouldn't occur, because the endpoint uses a valid certificate signed by VeriSign. Futhermore, it never occured in the Windows environment. A little trial and error showed that not a single certificate was being accepted by Mule. That would seem to point at Mule *or* Java since it doesn't seem to be able to use any of the default certificates. I managed to fix it by creating a key store containing all certificates and having my HTTPS connector reference that, but it means changing all my applications and having to scrape together every single certificate.

So my question is twofold:

1. Why can't Java/Mule use the default key store?
2. How do I fix it?

**EDIT + ANSWER:**
I've fixed it. It seems to have been my own mistake. I installed Java 1.6 after I installed Java 1.7. This seemed to have rolled my cacerts back to some ancient version which the system was unable to update. When I installed Java 1.6 and installed Java 1.7 after that, the most recent version got installed.

Comment: Just sanity checking: you're running the same JVM on Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: That's of course a valid question. The answer is yes. In fact: I've tried both my available runtimes on Ubuntu, 1.6 and 1.7, just to make sure. FYI: my dev-machine is running 1.7 and I've checked that the 1.7 install on Ubuntu is valid (using normal means like a clean reinstall, integrity check and random file check).

Comment: OK thanks, they're all Oracle JVMs right? Also how old is the `ca-certificates-java` package on your Ubuntu server?

Comment: The cacerts is dated on 2013-07-16. As for the package itself: 
Package: ca-certificates-java
Version: 20110912ubuntu6
Depends: ca-certificates (>= 20090814), openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b16-1.6.1-2) | java6-runtime-headless, libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.9+ckbi-1.82-0ubuntu3~)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. It seems to have been my own mistake. I installed Java 1.6 after I installed Java 1.7. This seemed to have rolled my cacerts back to some ancient version which the system was unable to update. When I installed Java 1.6 and installed Java 1.7 after that, the most recent version got installed.

So the lesson learned in this: do not install an older JRE after a newer one. Mule does not like it.